# Trouble installing PyAutoGUI on Python 3.8 (64-bit Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I am getting an error when I am installing PyAutoGUI and I cannot find out the problem. I tried installing it using pip. I also installed it using Anaconda but I cannot import it into Python. Any help is appreciated.

Version: Python 3.8

OS: Windows 10

Command Used: pip install pyautogui

Error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-j7d0dtw8\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
           cwd: None
      Complete output (14 lines):
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
          return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
        File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
          exec(code, run_globals)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
          from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 5, in <module>
          import locale
        File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\locale.py", line 16, in <module>
          import re
        File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\re.py", line 145, in <module>
          class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
      AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
      ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-j7d0dtw8\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-install your python installation or try using a different version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It gave me an idea which helped me install it!

Answer (score 0):

After Hitesh's answer, I tried downgrading my pip version to 1.2.1 and installed it again which worked. A huge thanks to Hitesh Patil!

Comment: what pip version did you use that ended up working?

Comment: I used version 1.2.1 `pip install pip==1.2.1`